# mRenderProp not returning the button

Tags: php, jquery, json, codeigniter, datatables

I am building a CRUD application which runs on Data-tables server-side processing, I managed to generate the  table dynamically but when I try to create a click-able button for viewing more information, it fails and only shows the  unique identifier. 
Please advise what am I not doing correctly at the  mRenderProp?
Below is my script that generates the  data-table :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        Draw();
        function Draw() {

            $('#example_ta').dataTable({
                "bJQueryUI": true,
                "bautoWidth": false,
                "aoColumns": [
                    {"sTitle": "Delivery Date", "mDataProp": "delivery_date"},
                    {"sTitle": "Delivery No.", "mDataProp": "delivery_no"},
                    {"sTitle": "Unit Code", "mDataProp": "unit_code"},
                    {"sTitle": "Driver Code.", "mDataProp": "driver_code"},
                    {"sTitle": "Zone Name.", "mDataProp": "zone_name"},
                    {"sTitle": "Zone Rate", "mDataProp": "zone_rate"},
                    {"sTitle": "Tonnage", "mDataProp": "tonnage"},
                    {"sTitle": "Standard Tonne", "mDataProp": "standard_tonne"},
                    {"sTitle": "View", "mDataProp": "delivery_id",
                        "mRenderProp": function (data, type, full) {
                            return '<button class="show-data btn btn-small btn-primary" id = ' + data + ' >View</button>';
                        }
                    },
                ],
                "bDeferRender": true,
                "bProcessing": true,
                "bDestroy": true,
                "bLengthChange": true,
                "iDisplayLength": 10,
                "sAjaxDataProp": "",
                "sAjaxSource": '<?php echo site_url() . "admin_profile/getDeliveries/"; ?>',
                "aaSorting": [[3, "asc"]]
            });
        }


    });

</script>
<table class="example_ta" id="example_ta">
    <thead>
        <tr>

        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        <tr></tr>
    </tbody>

</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's just `mRender` not `mRenderProp` - see [docs](http://legacy.datatables.net/usage/columns#mRender)

```
{"sTitle": "View", "mDataProp": "delivery_id",
                        "mRender": function (data, type, full) {
                            return '<button class="show-data btn btn-small btn-primary" id = ' + data + ' >View</button>';
                        }
```